# React countdown timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a countdown timer snippet in react as below:

```
const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime]: [number, Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>] = useState<number>(0);
const [updatedTime, setUpdatedTime]: [number, Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>] = useState<number>(0);
const referenceTime = useRef<number>(0); // new Date().getTime()
const intervalRef = useRef<number>(updatedTime);

const decreaseTime = () =>
        setUpdatedTime((prevState) => {
            if (prevState > 1) {
                    return parseFloat(((updatedTime * 1000 + referenceTime.current - Date.now()) / 1000).toFixed(0));
            } else {
                setRemainingTime(0);
                return 0;
            }
        });
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (remainingTime > 0) {
            intervalRef.current = setInterval(decreaseTime, 1000) as unknown as number;
        }

        return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
}, [remainingTime]);
```

Everything works fine till I want to add an increment and decrement option to it. It is necessary to use Date.now() and the referenceTime because this module is used in react-native and it must work in background mode, so where should I change something to upgrade the state correctly. I tried the below solutions:

```
setUpdatedTime((prevState) => prevState + 10)
```

and

```
setUpdatedTime((prevState) => updatedTime + 10)
```

Update:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-countdown-timer-lr9sb

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: How about using moment.js - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/ to work better with date & times.

Comment: Actually, I don't have to mutate the Date object, my problem is that the updatedTime not updated correctly.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is then?

Comment: @DrewReese if I try to add or subtract some seconds the countdown timer became crazy because the prevState and the updatedTime didn't change at the same time, so I set a new value for the updatedTime it will change for a render cycle but in the nextState is jumping back to the prevState. For example, my timer's state is 45 I add +10 sec then it will be 55/54 for a sec then jump back to 44.

Comment: @DrewReese I attached a codesanbox it will maybe help to see what is actually bad.

Comment: Hmm, it should be work. I tried in an incognito state.

Comment: I updated the link try it again maybe.

Comment: If you are counting down from a specific number, decrementing each second, why are you even mucking with a dateTime in the `decreaseTime` callback in the interval?

Comment: I need this method in react-native, but If take the app in bg mode on iOS the setInterval stops after 30 seconds so I need to cheat with real dates to update the state after Appstate changed back to active.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to understand why you've both a static value you're counting down from ***and*** some comparison to DateTime, in the state updater function in `decreaseTime`. Seems you'd want to compute a "time remaining" and just decrement that, and if the app is backgrounded, capture the current now time and the remaining to compute an expiration dateTime, and when the app is resumed, read the expiration to initialize the "time remaining" state and restart the interval.

Comment: Yes because the setInterval will kill the app on iOS and sometimes on Android too or execute after 30 seconds. The other way that I try using the bg process for that is but the systems don't allow it or just I don't know how it works. :D

Comment: It seems I cloud solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution if somebody is in the same situation:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-countdown-timer-lr9sb?file=/src/App.tsx

```
const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime]: [number, Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>] = useState<number>(0);
const [updatedTime, setUpdatedTime]: [number, Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>] = useState<number>(0);
const referenceTime = useRef<number>(0); // new Date().getTime()
const intervalRef = useRef<number>(updatedTime);

const decreaseTime = () =>
        setUpdatedTime((prevState) => {
            const difference = parseFloat((Date.now() - referenceTime.current - 1000).toFixed(0))
            if (prevState > 1) {
                    return parseFloat(((prevState * 1000 + referenceTime.current - Date.now() + (difference)) / 1000).toFixed(0));
            } else {
                setRemainingTime(0);
                return 0;
            }
        });
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (remainingTime > 0) {
            intervalRef.current = setInterval(decreaseTime, 1000) as unknown as number;
        }

        return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
}, [remainingTime]);
```

Comment: Just a cursory glance, but I think you've essentially `(prevState * 1000 + ref.current - now + (now - ref.current - 1000)) / 1000` which simplifies to `(prevState * 1000 - 1000) / 1000` => `(1000 / 1000) * (prevState * 1 - 1) / 1`, or `prevState  - 1`. It seems the now time is irrelevant if this solution is working for you. So this is correctly computing the next state even after being backgrounded for some time (30+ seconds)?

Comment: It is a good question I didn't think about I will test it. :D